# How to make an array of all items in a table

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I am trying to get all the rows in a table and return the results:

```
try{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = $this->status ORDER BY id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
    closeConnection();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

and then send the array to index:

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

It only displays 1 item and not all of the items in the table?

Comment: What do you think `fetch` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It only displays 1 item and not all of the items in the table?

[**From the PHP manual on PDOStatement::fetch**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

> Fetches **a** row from a result set associated with a PDOStatement object. The fetch_style parameter determines how PDO returns the row.

As you can see fetch is documented to return a single row. You need to iterate over the entire result set.

```
$results = array();
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($results, $row);
    }
}
// you should call closeConnection() here but 
// but closing PDO connections does not have to be done explicitly
return $results;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `fetchAll` instead of `fetch` to fetch all rows